# session object in rspec integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, rspec2, capybara

I am using rspec and capybara for integration testing.

Is their a way to make session objects in request specs?

I have a view page in which I use a session object to check its value to display selective content.

The problem am facing is that I cannot create a session object in request spec.
Here is an example of the view:

```
<% if session[:role] == "Role" %>
---content---
<% else %>
--content--
<% end %>
```

And inside my request spec

```
session[:role] = "Role"
visit my_path
```

But it throws me an error "undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass".

I also tried looking into creating session objects of capybara.But couldnt find anything.

Is their any workaround for this? I can not find  anything related to this, it seems that it is not possible.A little help is really appreciated.

Comment: Inside the if condition you probably meant == instead of =.

Comment: yes m sorry, i meant ==  here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are supposed to do request specs is visit whatever URL the user would normally need to visit in order for that session variable to be set.

I don't know of any other way, other perhaps than setting the session cookie by hand. `Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.set_cookie` let's you do this but you would have to create the cookie value by hand.

Comment: i tried this : cookies[:role] = "Coaching",
    Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.set_cookie(cookies[:role]) ,, but not working.what m i doing wrong?

Comment: That won't set the session. You would need to reproduce how rails generates session cookies and use the output of that in the call to set_cookie. You're definitely off the beaten path here - like i said the usual approach is just to visit the page that sets the session

Comment: in my case i sets these sessions in a private method in application controller.

Comment: sure, but there must be some page you can view on the site that ends up calling that method. With a request spec you should be reproducing the interactions that a normal user would do with their browser to end up in the desired state